# load external html into a div replaces content of original page with external html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using this code to put the contents of an external html

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('#topdiv').load("2-0.html");
```

when the page loads, instead of putting that html into the div with id topdiv, it just reloads the whole page and puts the new html instead of my index.html

the external html just has a twitter widget from the official twitter website in a div

```
<div style="float:right; margin:5px;">
<script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
<script>
    new TWTR.Widget({  
        version: 2,  
        type: 'search',  
        search: '#abbaseya',  
        interval: 15000,  
        subject: 'widget',  
        width: 300,  
        height: 360,
        theme: {
            shell: {      
                background: '#8ec1da',      
                color: '#ffffff'    
            },
            tweets: {      
                background: '#ffffff', 
                color: '#444444',      
                links: '#1985b5'    
            }  
        },
        features: {    
            scrollbar: true,    
            loop: true,    
            live: true,    
            behavior: 'default'  
        }
    }).render().start();
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load external html into a div - page loads then goes blank](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691051/load-external-html-into-a-div-page-loads-then-goes-blank) ... update your original question and be patient ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
var counter = 0;
var timer = null;
function progressBar(){
    if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = null;
        return;
    }
    timer = window.setInterval(function(){

     $('#topdiv').load("2-0.html");

    }, 10);
}

window.onload = function() {
    progressBar();
};
```

This works. Every millisecond reload the page.